# get Absolute Path for a library file in java plugin

Tags: java, plugins

I am developing a java plugin. In one case I need to pass address of some jar file (located in library directory) to another third library. However, I do not know how to obtain the address of the libraries located in the plugin.

I used the below code to find the plugin location (if I have that then I can add library folder to the end of it and pass that as jar address):

```
String pluginLocation = getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
```

It returns the below string:

/D:/eclipse/../workspace/JavaProject/my.plugin/

However, the address that I need is  "D:/workspace/JavaProject/my.plugin/"

Please let me know how can I get the right path?

Comment: Is there a problem directly using the returned String? `../` is just up 1 directory - so technically those path's are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with eclipse seeing as I use Intellij myself but maybe adding it a resource folder would work. or maybe its reading plugin from different folder. If that doesn't help I guess you can try trimming the string